# Is it possible to use SharedPreferences two times in one widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I tried to safe **two** `ints` with `SharedPreferences` in one file. I don´t know if that is possible, because I can only save one of them. I´m not sure if I made a mistake in the code or if it´s not possible to save to different values in **one** `StatefulWidget`. Does anybody see a mistake in my code or can tell me if it is theoretically possible to safe two values in one file? Below is the code of my two safe requests.

Safe requests one (that one **works**):

```
 int lastLoginInt = 1;
 String nameKey = "_key_name";
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> saveLastLoginInt() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setInt(nameKey, lastLoginInt);
  }

  Future<int> loadLastLoginInt() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getInt(nameKey);
  }

  setLastLoginInt() {
    loadLastLoginInt().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        lastLoginInt = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

And this is my second request (which **doesn´t work**):

```
String nameKey1 = "_key_name2";
int countInt = 0;
Future<bool> saveCount() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setInt(nameKey1, countInt);
  }

  Future<int> loadCount() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getInt(nameKey1);
  }

  setCount() {
    loadLastLoginInt().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        countInt = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

Hopefully it´s an easy to solve problem. Thank´s in advance!

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: The setCount method doesn't work?

Comment: I´m not sure if the setCount or the saveCount method doesn´t work...

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the value saved from saveCount in setCount?

Comment: @Locked yes exactly

Comment: The problem is with the key then

Comment: What? No. Your `setCount()` is calling `loadLastLoginInt()` instead of `loadCount()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible and its allowed. I've loaded multiple values from SharedPrefs while making a settings page etc.

You're just calling `loadLastLoginInt()` instead of `loadCount()`

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadLastLoginInt` uses key `nameKey` while your `saveCount` use `nameKey1`.

`nameKey = "_key_name"` 
`nameKey1 = "_key_name2`

Try using the same value for both variables.

Or 
Allow your setCount call `loadCount` instead of `loadLastLoginInt`

```
setCount() {
    loadCount().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        countInt = value;
      });
    });
  }
```